# How can I get product information intoa database without having to populate it manually?

Tags: database, api, web-applications, data-mining, dynamic-data

I am looking for a method of dynamically linking product information based on the name of the product.

For example:  User types in "Playstation 3", the site would then go out and grab any information it can, such as picture, retail price, etc.  Ideally, it would let you choose the correct item (returns both ps3 controller and ps3 console, user can choose which).  It would then use this information in a product listing.

The easiest way I can think to implement this is to use the existing API of a major retailer such as Amazon.  I have a couple completely different ideas for sites, one of which would involve selling from amazon (which I would assume they would be ok with) and another which would only be data mining the information. I am concerned they would not take it very kindly if I was just stealing their images and descriptions.

Is there another way, maybe less "sneaky" way to accomplish this that wouldn't be in legally frowned upon ?

Answer (score 0):

Many web-commerce companies use a data stream known as an API - EBay, Etsy, and Amazon all have API feeds for their products. If you can convince the company to allow you access to their API (usually they will give you a key/password), then you can directly access their back-end database, typically at the read-only level. Depending on the company, you can just write them directly for access.

You are correct when you say that most companies wouldn't take kindly to someone web-scraping their product directory and re-using it. That is unethical, and could lead to big trouble with larger companies with a significant legal presence.

On the other hand, there is nothing to prevent you from cobbling together several API feeds into a Mash-Up - try Yahoo Pipes! to learn the basics of API/Mash-Up integration:

Yahoo Pipes:

http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/

Here is the link to Amazon's Product Advertising API program:

https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html

Good luck, and happy development!

Answer (score 0):

Many online retailers provide a product feed - either well-publicized (William M-B has listed some examples), or sorta-kinda hidden, for the purposes of affiliate marketing. They usually have terms of use around those product feeds, describing in detail what you're allowed to do with them, and exactly how many of your limbs are at risk if you don't play by their rules.

However, the mechanism you're describing sounds remarkably similar to a search engine; there's a well-established precedent for search engines indexing sites, and using their content to reason about the underlying site. Get a lawyer to validate this, but there's a good chance that your intended purpose falls under "fair use".

Answer (score 0):

I'm representative of http://aerse.com.

We are building service, that do the following:

- search product by name. For example: [galaxy s3](http://aerse.com/f?r=galaxy%20s3), [galaxy s 3](http://aerse.com/f?r=galaxy%20s%203) or [galaxy sIII](http://aerse.com/f?r=galaxy%20sIII)
- return technical specifications (CPU, RAM etc) and product images (thumbnails and high-res images)
- provide API http://aerse.com/p
- deal with legal issues, provide licenses & etc.